# how to initialize bootstrap data table on thymeleaf fragment

Tags: datatables, thymeleaf

I am using a bootstrap datatable on thymeleaf fragment, but the datatable is not getting initialized when i load the fragment using AJAX call. How do i call datatable initialization on fragment load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for this. In order to load fragment using ajax call i am using the below snippet

```
 $('#divid').load(url)
```

Above code snippet will load the dynamically generated ajax fragment to the divid div. Now the solution is to initialize the datatable on 'complete' of load url

```
 $('#divid').load(url,function() {$('#datatableid').DataTable();});
```

Please refer to the [jquery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Also if you need to specify any events to any specific html components (like button) in the fragment, then in order for the events to work, you may also specify the event handling javascripts on complete function like below (cancel is a button in my fragment.

```
 $('#divid').load(url,function() {
    $('#datatableid').DataTable();
    $('.cancel').click(function(){
    });
});
```